# jquery hover function

Tags: jquery

```
var h=0;
var w=0;
    $(".extend").hover(function() {

        //alert(h);
        $(this).css({'z-index' : '999' });
        $(this).addClass("hover").filter(":not(:animated)").stop()
            .animate({
                marginTop: '-110px', 
                marginLeft: '10px', 
                top: '80%', 
                left: '80%',
                width: 387, 
                height: 487,
                padding: '0px' 
            }, 200);
         h=$(this).height();
         w=$(this).width();
        } , function() {
        $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
        $(this).removeClass("hover").stop()
            .animate({
                marginTop: '0', 
                marginLeft: '0',
                top: '0', 
                left: '0', 
                width:w,
                height:h,
                padding: '0px'
            }, 400);
    });

<img class="extend" src="a.jpg">
<img class="extend" src="b.jpg">
```

I have problem with my hover function i can't make the image back to original size if i hover it to a.jpg it expand then i hover over to b.jpg without waiting a.jpg to return to original size it will become bigger and bigger.

How i can hover and expand without shifting the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need your width and height to change, you should only set it once, assuming both images are the same size this should work

```
var h=$(".extend").height();
var w=$(".extend").width();
    $(".extend").hover(function() {

        //alert(h);
        $(this).css({'z-index' : '999' });
        $(this).addClass("hover").filter(":not(:animated)").stop()
            .animate({
                marginTop: '-110px', 
                marginLeft: '10px', 
                top: '80%', 
                left: '80%',
                width: 387, 
                height: 487,
                padding: '0px' 
            }, 200);
        } , function() {
        $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
        $(this).removeClass("hover").stop()
            .animate({
                marginTop: '0', 
                marginLeft: '0',
                top: '0', 
                left: '0', 
                width:w,
                height:h,
                padding: '0px'
            }, 400);
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/WSqve/)

EDIT--
For images with different dimensions save them in the element using .data()

```
$(".extend").each(function(){
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
})
$(".extend").hover(function() {

    //alert(h);
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '999' });
    $(this).addClass("hover").filter(":not(:animated)").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '-110px', 
            marginLeft: '10px', 
            top: '80%', 
            left: '80%',
            width: 387, 
            height: 487,
            padding: '0px' 
        }, 200);
    } , function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
    $(this).removeClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '0', 
            marginLeft: '0',
            top: '0', 
            left: '0', 
            width:$(this).data('width'),
            height:$(this).data('height'),
            padding: '0px'
        }, 400);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/WSqve/1/)

EDIT-2-
A simple way to solve the shifting problem is to wrap the img tags in an inline-block element, set the elements dimensions to that of the image then make the img absolutly positioned

```
<span><img class="extend" src="a.jpg"></span>
<span><img class="extend" src="b.jpg"></span>​

$(".extend").each(function(){
    $(this).data('width', $(this).width());
    $(this).data('height', $(this).height());
    $(this).parent().css({display:'inline-block', width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height()})
    .end().css({position:'absolute'});
})
$(".extend").hover(function() {

    //alert(h);
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '999' });
    $(this).addClass("hover").filter(":not(:animated)").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '-110px', 
            marginLeft: '10px', 
            top: '80%', 
            left: '80%',
            width: 387, 
            height: 487,
            padding: '0px' 
        }, 200);
    } , function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
    $(this).removeClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '0', 
            marginLeft: '0',
            top: '0', 
            left: '0', 
            width:$(this).data('width'),
            height:$(this).data('height'),
            padding: '0px'
        }, 400);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/WSqve/2/)

Comment: It works but it still didn't solve the align problem when the image expand. The element beside the image will shift as the image expand. How to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is strange it works on the fiddle but not on my webpage what is the possible problem? all my image is being shift to the top left of the frame.

Comment: It may be affected by the css on the webpage or there might be errors in the script on the page which stops execution, many other reasons

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
 $(".extend").hover(function() {

    //alert(h);
     h=$(this).height();
     w=$(this).width();
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '999' });
    $(this).data('width', w);
    $(this).data('height',h);
    $(this).addClass("hover").filter(":not(:animated)").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '-110px', 
            marginLeft: '10px', 
            top: '80%', 
            left: '80%',
            width: 387, 
            height: 487,
            padding: '0px' 
        }, 200);

    } , function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
    h=$(this).data('height');
     w=$(this).data('width');
    $(this).removeClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '0', 
            marginLeft: '0',
            top: '0', 
            left: '0', 
            width:w,
            height:h,
            padding: '0px'
        }, 400);
});
```

Comment: tested not working when i shifting my mouse in and out super fast speed it get bigger and bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Since `w` and `h` are globals, every time you hover a new element, they grow bigger and bigger.

Store them inside of the actual element using `.data()` attributes:

```
$(".extend").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '999' });
    $(this).addClass("hover").filter(":not(:animated)").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '-110px', 
            marginLeft: '10px', 
            top: '80%', 
            left: '80%',
            width: 387, 
            height: 487,
            padding: '0px' 
        }, 200);

     $(this).data('original-height', $(this).height());
     $(this).data('original-width', $(this).width());

    } , function() {
    $(this).css({'z-index' : '0'});
    $(this).removeClass("hover").stop()
        .animate({
            marginTop: '0', 
            marginLeft: '0',
            top: '0', 
            left: '0', 
            width:$(this).data('original-width'),
            height:$(this).data('original-height'),
            padding: '0px'
        }, 400);
});
```

Comment: tested not working when i shifting my mouse in and out super fast speed it get bigger and bigger. my text beside it still being push to right